# back button color change

Tags: java, android

[image]

Any solution for to make the above back button color white please help me with my code as i am a student don't refer me to another question

Below is my code

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text, not a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You are using android:iconTint replace it with below code and use **app:iconTint**

```
    app:iconTint="@color/white"
```

Comment: Still it's not working

Comment: Post the xml code that's weird